# Org-mode: org-agenda-files defvar directory "evaluation"?

Tags: lisp, elisp, org-mode

I have the following setup in my .emacs ...

```
(defvar org-dir "/home/mash/read/org/")
```

And use it around such as ...

```
(setq org-directory org-dir)
(setq org-default-notes-file (concat org-dir "mash.org"))
```

Now I understand that you can specify a directory such as ...

```
(setq org-agenda-files '("/home/mash/read/org/"))
```

But how would I do this with the variable?

```
(setq org-agenda-files '(org-dir))
(setq org-agenda-files '(,(org-dir))
```

Any ideas as I would like to use it in my capture templates too ...

```
(setq org-capture-templates
  '(("t" "Test" entry (file+headline (concat org-dir "test.org" "test")
      "* %?")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'(foo bar)` syntax is equivalent to writing `(list 'foo 'bar)`.  So you can set `org-agenda-files` like this:

```
(setq org-agenda-files (list org-dir))
```

Alternatively, you can replace the apostrophe `'` with a backtick ` to create a list and then use comma to evaluate a part of that list

```
(setq org-capture-templates
  `(("t" "Test" entry (file+headline ,(concat org-dir "test.org" "test")
      "* %?")))
```

Comment: Great thanks, using `list` works. Strange you can't use `'`? Also I seem to be able to just use `concat` in the capture template. I did try using a `,` before but I got "old-style" warnings.

Comment: The difference between the quotes `'` and ` is that there is no way to evaluate an expression within a list quoted by `'`.  I.e. you can write `(,(+ 1 2)) which will eval to `(3)`, but `'(,(+ 1 2)) will eval to `(\, (+ 1 2)).  The wikipedia entry to quasi-quotation is probably helpful in this context.